# Objective-C++ converting std::string to NSString

Tags: c++, string, nsstring, objective-c++

I would like to write an objective-C++ program in such a way that I could write:

```
class foo
{
public:
foo()
{
    bar = "Hello world";
}
std::string bar;
};
```

Then (below in the same .mm file) I could create an instance of that class then do something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    foo* thisWontWork = new foo();
    self.myLabel.text = foo.bar; //this doesn't work obviously

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

which would effectively change the text of label 'myLabel' to "Hello world"

Comment: self.myLabel.text = thisWontWork->bar ?

Comment: oh, yeah that is a std::string :).. `self.myLabel.text = @(thisWontWork->bar.c_str())`

Comment: do you want to copy the data in the string, or do you want an NSString that presents the data in the c++ string without taking ownership?

Comment: If theres another way that the below answer didn't cover I would be happy to see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
self.myLabel.text = @(foo->bar.c_str());
```

Which converts `std::string` to `const char *` to `NSString`.

But note: you are leaking `foo`, so:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    foo _foo;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

and use:

```
self.myLabel.text = @(_foo.bar.c_str());
```

Comment: What do you mean leaking foo?

Comment: @user235236 You are calling `new` and you never call `delete`.